# Problema plicas e IF php

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';' in

Tenho esse erro na segunda linha deste codigo:

```
echo '<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Ficha de Aptidão Médica Validade: if ($exibe['MedicaValidade']) { 
if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()) {
    echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MedicaValidade'].'</span>';
} else {
    echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];
}
} else { 
echo 'N/D';}</p>
```

Comment: Poxa... 6 down-votes só porque o cara não sabe PHP. Tá difícil de aprender algo novo hoje em dia! =\

Comment: pqp. Aí é sacanagem. Cara, só uma dica, escreve primeiro echo '   '; e ali dentro tu coloca o HTML. Desta forma não vai se confundir.

Answer (score 7):

Segue "conserto" pro seu código:

```
echo '<div id="tabs-2">';
echo '<p>Ficha de Aptidão Médica Validade:';
if ($exibe['MedicaValidade']) { 
   if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()) {
      echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MedicaValidade'].'</span>';
   } else {
      echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];
   }
} else { 
   echo 'N/D';
}
echo '</p>';
```

Como você aparentemente não tem experiência com PHP, evite quebrar as linhas pra não se confundir. Procure usar um echo pra cada linha, e abrir e fechar as plicas (ápices, na verdade) corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

Os erros estão nas aspas e no código HTML concatenado ao PHP.
Tente desta forma:

```
echo "<div id='tabs-2'> <p>Ficha de Aptidão Médica Validade: "; 
if ($exibe['MedicaValidade']) { 
    if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()) {
        echo "<span style='color:red'>" . $exibe['MedicaValidade']."</span>";
    } else {
        echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];
    }
} else { 
    echo "N/D";
}
echo "</p>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Sintaxe Correta: você estava colocando tudo misturado Html com PHP e não pode...

```
<?php
   echo '<div id="tabs-2"><p>Ficha de Aptidão Médica Validade:';
   if ($exibe['MedicaValidade']) { 
       if (strtotime($exibe['MedicaValidade']) < time()) 
       {
           echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['MedicaValidade'].'</span>';
       } else {
           echo $exibe['MedicaValidade'];
       }
   } else { 
       echo 'N/D';
   }
   echo '</p></div>';
?>
```

*Obs: Cuidado com a junção do Html com sintaxe PHP percebe que uma simples organização foi o suficiente para achar o erro.*