# Fazer uma tela de descanso com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Preciso fazer uma tela de descanso, quando o mouse ficar parado por alguns segundos abre a *div* de descanso, tentei isso sem sucesso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
   }, 10000);

});
</script>
```

Quando o mouse mover novamente a *div* some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem aqui um exemplo: ([PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/FijfgBf3EBoGGk4Te0Ti))

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var timeout = setTimeout(showTela, 3000);
    $(document).mousemove(onEvent);
    $(document).mousedown(onEvent);
    $(document).keydown(onEvent);


    function onEvent() {
      $('#tela').hide();
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(showTela, 3000);
    }

    function showTela() {
      $("#tela").show();
    }
  });
```

Basicamente o que falta no seu script é fazer reset no timer quando o rato mexe.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer um assim:

```
var s_saver;

$('body').mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(s_saver);

    s_saver = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#screensaver').fadeIn(900);
    }, 4000);

    $('#screensaver').fadeOut(100);
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ag9fr/)</kbd>

O efeito é causado pelo [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) que deixa os elementos opacos e [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) que esconde os elementos até ficarem transparentes. No exemplo acima isso acontece após quatro segundos, quando ocorre o evento [`.mousemove`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) a contagem é reiniciada.

<sub>[**`Fonte`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745111/1608936)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer assim:

```
var ultimoMovimento = new Date();
var janela = $('#janela');
$(window).on('mousemove', function () {
    ultimoMovimento = new Date();
    janela.hide();
});
var verificar = setInterval(function () {
    var agora = new Date();
    var diferenca = (agora.getTime() - ultimoMovimento.getTime()) / 1000;
    if (diferenca > 10) janela.show();

}, 3000);
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/29bPR/)

A minha ideia é:

- registrar a hora (em milisegundos) quando a página carrega, e cada vez que o mouse tem movimento.
- verificar a cada 3 segundos se a diferença entre a hora nesse momento e a hora registrada antes é maior que 10 segundos.
- mostra a janela quando o tempo parado for mais do que 10 segundos
- esconde a janela quando o mouse mexe

---

Outra variante é ter uma função auxiliar que (re)começa uma contagem decrescente quando o mouse move.

```
function esperar() {

    janela.hide();
    var limpar;
    clearInterval(limpar);
    limpar = setTimeout(function () {
        janela.show();
    }, 10000); // 10 segundos, 10 000 milisegundos
}

var janela = $('#janela');
$(window).on('mousemove', esperar);
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/E6Jk7/)

Comment: O @brasofilo não gosta de PT_pt :)

Comment: OMG, em pt_PT o registrar não tem esse R? Sorry... Já me estranhava, o mesmo erro tipografico 2x, lição aprendida :)

Comment: @brasofilo acontece :) . Outro dia eu apanhei pra descobrir o que eram "plicas".

Comment: @Bacco, comPlicas, exPlicas?

Comment: @brasofilo :) não tem mal, aí eu aprendí como se diz em PT_br

Comment: @brasofilo, na hora que eu li o título não entendi "plica" nenhuma: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13027/problema-plicas-e-if-php

Comment: @Sergio, eu acho que é `lingua_PAIS` :P Adoro esta co-existência no SOPT, cada hora aprendo uma variante nova.